# How to hide the label at the bottom of the page in select directory page in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I want to remove the label at the bottom of the page where  i select the directory to install the components. The label shows minimum disk space required to install applications.

Comment: share some content to get a better answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to hide the `DiskSpaceLabel` control:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Visible := False;
end;
```

That will hide the label marked on this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank u TLama. i am able to hide the label